# Invalid Macro definition in doskey

Tags: powershell, macros

```
fp=c:\Rational\ClearCase\etc\utils\fix_prot.exe -force -chgrp "TheNewGroup" -chown yourID $*
fp -rec -chmod 775 \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws
fp -root \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws
```

I tried to execute above command in Windows PowerShell and it throws an error like

> "fp" Term not recognized by cmdlet.

or

> Invald macro definition.

But I used `macros:all` command to view all macros which is present in `doskey`. `fp` macro is available.

Answer (score 0):

Doskey macros are built into CMD, not PowerShell. To get a similar behavior in PowerShell you could define a function with a catchall parameter:

```psh
function fp {
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]$params
  )

  & 'C:\Rational\ClearCase\etc\utils\fix_prot.exe' -force -chgrp 'TheNewGroup' -chown yourID @params
}
```

and add that function to your [profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx).

PowerShell [aliases](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/04/21/when-you-should-use-powershell-aliases.aspx) won't work here, because you want to specify a default argument set, but in PowerShell you can only alias commands, not entire commandlines.